# Is there a Fuji X10 raw converter for Linux?

Tags: raw, fujifilm, linux

Does anyone know if there's away to convert Fuji X10 Raw files in Ubuntu?

I'm considering to buy this camera but most software I've seen doesn't support it or isn't clear regarding that issue.

**Update**: I mean full support, I understand Raw Therapee has limited support (if you're a x10/RT user please share your thoughts on the comments)

Comment: I have a fuji XF1 which has the same sensor as the X10. I'm running Ubuntu 12.04 I'm inexperienced working with raw files. The XF1 raw files imported to Darktable and Raw Therapee have incorrect colors, seems red is blue. I was able to correct this in Darktable by choosing a different input color profile: 'Linear Infrared BGR'
I don't know why but with that color profile everything looks as it should.
I couldn't fix it in Raw Therapee, so I can't use that. Anyway Darktable seems to have many more features than RawTherapee. I also installed Fuji's Silkypix (for Windows) in Ubuntu using Wine. It

Comment: "Full support" doesn't really mean anything specific.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The issue you're going to have is two-fold.

The X10's EXR sensor is not something other cameras have, save for a couple of Fuji cameras. The EXR sensor can do a lot of things with the available pixels in the sensor and that is why their RAW files are a little odd compared to those of say the X-Pro1 or 100 which use the X-Trans sensors.

You'll potentially have a RAW image that contains the pairs of pixels, and a lot of RAW software doesn't expect there to be a 12mp sensor with a 6mp image, twice.  When you're using the EXR modes on the dial you cannot also capture RAW, but you can force the camera to use the EXR sensor in this way by setting the size of your image from Large to Medium and then use RAW+JPEG.

In-camera RAW conversion to JPEG will do the binning of those pixels properly and always get great results (though believe me, I can understand not wanting to sit around with your camera in your lap for an hour doing trial and error conversions on a 2" LCD.)

Fuji doesn't publish the format on these to my knowledge, which is why there isn't native support for the X10's RAW in Aperture. Adobe Lightroom will convert it to Adobe DNG, or you can use the Adobe DNG converter, which may or may not help you (I don't know if there is a DNG converter for computers running FOSS).

Ultimately if FOSS compatibility and capability for RAW is really important to you, the X10 isn't going to make it easy for you (or even mildly annoying); there are better purchases within those constraints.  The quirks of the X10 (or any other camera) take some practice and experience; I'm not delighted with the way I'm handling the X10's RAF RAW on OS X and Aperture, but at least I have the benefit of being able to make do with DNG converter.  I knew that I'd have some rough ground to cover before I purchased it, but after using the X-Pro1 for a while (and having it outside of my budget) I couldn't see myself liking anything else more.

Update: I have used dcraw and ufraw-batch and made TIF and PNG images, they were pretty good.  The JEPGs out of the camera are arguably better though, which is further evidence that the RAW-to-X software out there (other than the bundled SilkyPix) may not always handle the binned data correctly.  Or I'm really bad at processing images (very likely!) and can't match the camera because I'm a dunce!

IMO, Fuji's quality control is outstanding, the X series are built in Japan and use excellent components. The 'White Orbs Problem' has never affected more than 1 out of 10,000 photos I've taken and if I sent in a camera for repair and it came back with dust in the lens I'd just send it back. It isn't like Fuji engineers are doing the labor on that.

Comment: Is the RAW format of the bigger X series better supported? I have the X10 too and I use FOSS almost 99% of the time, so I ended up shooting in always in JPEG :( But I'd really like to get an X-M1 or X-E1 (to shoot in RAW, of course).

Comment: @incumbent - If you log in first, you should be able to make a comment. The comment you edited into your answer is showing as an anonymous submission, not from you. Try logging out them back in.

Comment: Thank you, @MichaelClark! Appending as a comment below: @fortran, the APS-C X-Trans sensor in the other X-series cameras (X-Pro1, X-E1, X100, X100s, etc.) is also different from traditional Bayer sensors, but is better supported than the EXR sensor by a wide variety of tools including dcraw. If I were using an Ubuntu workstation or something I'd be probably using darktable instead of Lightroom, which should be able to handle the X-Trans RAF files. Before buying a new camera find sample RAW files to test with!

Comment: It seems that darktable does not support X-trans nor it is planned any support soon...http://www.darktable.org/2012/10/whats-involved-with-adding-support-for-new-cameras/

Comment: 'dcraw' has support for the X-Trans, and darktable will use 'dcraw' according to their documentation.

Answer (score 8):

Fuji X10 is supported by [dcraw](http://www.cybercom.net/~dcoffin/dcraw/).

Maybe [UFRaw](http://ufraw.sourceforge.net/index.html) will support that one too, thought it does not contain the camera on supported cameras list. UFRaw uses dcraw as its backend.

Comment: Looking at http://ufraw.sourceforge.net/Cameras.html, various Fuji X models are listed. And a note in the end of this page, states: _UFRaw should convert raw images from all of the above digital cameras without descrimination, no matter if you are working on Linux, Mac or MS-Windows._

Answer (score 3):

Neither DCRaw or UFRaw works. They both saw that the RAF (Fuji raw file) is corrupted.

[Edit]

F-Spot View (f-spot.org) is able to display them, so I'm sure there is a way to convert them.

BTW, if you haven't bought it yet, be sure that the one you buy do not have the White Orbs issue. The only way to be sure is to take picture of intense reflections or direct light. I just got mine back from Fujifilm. The White Orbs is fixed, but now I have dust in the lenses. Fujifilm quality control is unacceptable... You are better buy one that already works and hope that it will never break.

The quality of the raw is not that great (at lease that's what DPreview said, I'm not with raw so I can not really tell).

Good luck!

Comment: The f-spot display is probably the embedded JPEG preview, not conversion.

Comment: Darktable, based on libgphoto2, claims it can handle X10, but couldn't find a way to verify it. 

As for the white orbs, there isn't a way to tell if a camera is affected or not before buying, so the only option is buying it and test.

Comment: Darktable 1.1.3 does not handle X10 sample files. I just checked this file: http://img.photographyblog.com/reviews/fujifilm_finepix_x10/sample_images/fujifilm_finepix_x10_01.raf

Answer (score 3):

The current unstable version of darktable includes full support for this camera and many others (including most or all modern Fujis). It uses rawspeed, a more modern raw parsing/decoding library, to handle it. An Ubuntu PPA that includes this support is available at:

https://launchpad.net/~pmjdebruijn/+archive/ubuntu/darktable-unstable

The normal disclaimers about unstable software apply. The next darktable stable release will include this support.

Answer (score 2):

[UFRaw](http://ufraw.sourceforge.net/) should now (since late 2014 / v0.20) [support Fuji X-Trans filters](http://ufraw.sourceforge.net/#News). The RAW files have been supported for a long time. Sample photos I've found convert well. I don't have your exact model to try with, but for anyone looking for an answer to this, you should try it.

[Darktable also has support in an experimental branch (1.5)](http://www.darktable.org/2014/08/using-x-trans-cameras-with-darktable/) and is expected to have it in the next stable (1.6) as well.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried Lightzone?  I have a Fuji XE1 and Lightzone works perfectly.  You can join and download for free from the project's website http://www.lightzoneproject.org/

Comment: Looks like LightZone uses dcraw for RAW support, so...

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried RawTherapee?  I'm not a photography expert, but it seems to work well for me on Windows.  I see they have linux downloads.

Link: http://rawtherapee.com/

Comment: I'm here looking for a solution to this problem because of RawTherapee. It seems to be a good program; displays a preview of the raw image from Fujifilm Finepix HS50EXR in good colours. But when you open the file it becomes "blued".

Comment: @André the preview would be from the Embedded image while the RAW would be from the actual RAW data - and if there is no camera profile available it will have a colour hue. Check if there is Fuji  colour profile - if there is you an assign it, else you would have to create your own or fix it by hand. You are aware that RAW is a "negative format" that looks best only after processing?